# Is the text of the New Vulgate protected by copyright?

Tags: bible

Recently there was a question on this site about different translations of the Bible, I am considering editing some passages in the form of a comparison between the different versions (one column per translation).

Is the New Vulgate copyrighted or can I use it freely?
I have not found any information on this subject in the [CONSTITUTIO APOSTOLICA](https://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_jp-ii_apost_const_lt.html).

Comment: I would suggest that this question be migrated to https://law.stackexchange.com/ – but in short, yes, translations are copyrighted works, and the NV is so recent that the copyright has certainly not expired. The use of excerpts that you have in mind does probably not require the Holy See's approval either way, but that may depend on your local law.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I mean, some recent work are released under more permissive licences, the European law applies in my case. I will ask on the other site, thanks for the answer